# How to get access token with less permissions to google analytic

Tags: javascript, client, google-oauth

We have website with JS api client for google.

That is our scenario:

1. We request refresh token with permissions for [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
                   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit']
2. For most of users that is exactly what we need.
3. However we have some read-only users for which we want to receive access_token with less permissions than our refresh token allows. In our case by refresh token we want receive access token with only "analytics.readonly" permission.

How can we down-grade access_token rights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do allow you to downscope a refresh token when you are trying to get an Access token. Just send the scopes to the "token endpoint" along with the refresh token and you'll get an access token with just the scopes requested. I'll add a link to the doc later.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to request authentication again this time only requesting readonly access.  There is no way to downgrade the access granted by a access token once it was created by the authentication server.